# Yocto - applying a bbappend file to a recipe (from github)

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I'm working with the meta-atmel layer in Yocto to create an image for a SAMA5D4 board.

I've created a custom layer & would like to patch a file (specifically https://github.com/linux4sam/egt/blob/master/src/app.cpp) with a diff I created:

```
index 869b1e2..c86ad1a 100644
--- a/app.cpp
+++ b/app.cpp.modified
@@ -342,8 +342,9 @@ void Application::setup_inputs()
         }
     }
 
+// Modify to force use of tslib
 #ifdef HAVE_LIBINPUT
-    m_inputs.push_back(std::make_unique<detail::InputLibInput>(*this));
+//    m_inputs.push_back(std::make_unique<detail::InputLibInput>(*this));
 #endif
 }
```

I recreated the directory structure in my custom layer to match the location of the file I'd like to alter:

yocto/meta-atmel/recipes-graphics/libegt/libegt_1.2.bb

yocto/meta-custom2/recipes-graphics/libegt/libegt_%.bbappend

My bbappend file is:

```
# Modify https://github.com/linux4sam/egt/src/app.cpp
# Issue with file path

SRC_URI += "file:0001-disable-libinput.patch"

FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"

PACKAGE_ARCH = "${MACHINE_ARCH}"
```

How do I correctly include my patchfile to the file I'd like to modify?

Many thanks for looking!

Answer (score 3):

Well looks like I may have solved the issue.

I moved my diff file to the directory:

yocto/meta-custom2/recipes-graphics/libegt/files

& corrected some errors:

Diff should be:

```
diff --git a/src/app.cpp b/src/app.cpp
index 869b1e2..c86ad1a 100644
--- a/src/app.cpp
+++ b/src/app.cpp
@@ -342,8 +342,9 @@ void Application::setup_inputs()
         }
     }

+// Modify to force use of tslib
 #ifdef HAVE_LIBINPUT
-    m_inputs.push_back(std::make_unique<detail::InputLibInput>(*this));
+//    m_inputs.push_back(std::make_unique<detail::InputLibInput>(*this));
 #endif
 }
```

where the '/src/app.cpp' referes to the location of the file that needs to be patched (i.e. similar if one carried out a git clone). Next my bbappend should have been:

```
# Modify https://github.com/linux4sam/egt/src/app.cpp

SRC_URI += "file://0001-disable-libinput.patch"

FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"

PACKAGE_ARCH = "${MACHINE_ARCH}"
```

Hope this helps others & thanks to the teams working on Yocto/ OE!